# Is it ok and not an anti pattern to nest scaffolds in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter 3.16.5 and have one mainscreen and a couple of other screens.
The main screen is using a bottomNavigationBar

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
```

And based on the selected bottom menu I show the other screens.
The mainscreen has already one scaffold.

The other screens have their own scaffolds as well..
Why?
Other screens:

1. Might have a different appbar and title on top
2. They might have different floating buttons each of them.

My simplified code for `MainScreen` is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final _navigationBloc = inject<NavigationBloc>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, MenuPage>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        final routeConfig = _routes[state]!;

        final currentPageIndex = _routes.keys.toList().indexOf(state);

        return Scaffold(
          body: routeConfig.content,
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              _navigationBloc.navigateTo(_routes.keys.toList()[index]);
            },
            currentIndex: currentPageIndex,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                label: S.of(context).menu_home,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                label: S.of(context).menu_profile,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

final Map<MenuPage, RouteConfig> _routes = {
  MenuPage.home: const RouteConfig('Home', HomeScreen(), showAppBar: false),
  MenuPage.profile: const RouteConfig('Profile', ProfileScreen(), showAppBar: false),
};

class RouteConfig {
  final String trackingTag;
  final Widget content;
  final bool showAppBar;

  const RouteConfig(this.trackingTag, this.content, {this.showAppBar = true});
}
```

Simplified `ProfileScreen` (important just to note that has its own `Scaffold` and in the future own appbar floatingbutton as well

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Profile Example Screen',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What are your thoughts ?
Is this nesting ok. If not please me suggest a proper flutter architecture for my described goal to have one main screen and a couple of other screens chosen from bottom menu, where each of them can have its own different floating button and appbar.

Answer (score 1):

[Nested Scaffolds](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html#:%7E:text=Troubleshooting-,Nested%20Scaffolds,-The%20Scaffold%20is)

> The Scaffold is designed to be a top level container for a
> MaterialApp. This means that adding a Scaffold to each route on a
> Material app will provide the app with Material's basic visual layout
> structure.
>
> It is typically not necessary to nest Scaffolds. For example, in a
> tabbed UI, where the bottomNavigationBar is a TabBar and the body is a
> TabBarView, you might be tempted to make each tab bar view a scaffold
> with a differently titled AppBar. Rather, it would be better to add a
> listener to the TabController that updates the AppBar
>
> Add a listener to the app's tab controller so that the AppBar title of
> the app's one and only scaffold is reset each time a new tab is
> selected.
>
> ```
> TabController(vsync: tickerProvider, length: tabCount)..addListener(() {
>   if (!tabController.indexIsChanging) {
>     setState(() {
>       // Rebuild the enclosing scaffold with a new AppBar title
>       appBarTitle = 'Tab ${tabController.index}';
>     });
>   }
> })
> ```
>
> Although there are some use cases, like a presentation app that shows
> embedded flutter content, where nested scaffolds are appropriate, it's
> best to avoid nesting scaffolds.

Nesting Scaffolds isn't generally recommended because it can lead to unexpected behaviour and a non-standard visual appearance. It might also introduce performance issues and complicate the widget tree unnecessarily. However, there are certain cases where you might intentionally nest Scaffolds, such as:

- Separate AppBar for Nested Routes: When you have nested navigators
  and you want to have a separate AppBar for the inner routes.
- Bottom Sheets: If you're showing a modal bottom sheet that contains
  tabs with their own app bars or other 'scaffolded' UI elements.
- Dialogs: Sometimes a dialog might require scaffold-like features,
  though this is less common with the availability of the AlertDialog
  and SimpleDialog widgets.

If you find yourself needing to nest Scaffold widgets, consider whether there's a more straightforward way to achieve your design. Often, using a combination of Container, Column, Row, and Stack widgets can provide the layout you need without the overhead or complications of multiple Scaffolds.

If you do need to nest scaffolds, ensure that you handle the navigation and UI elements (like drawers and snack bars) correctly to avoid conflicts and confusion in the UI.